# Center a title but subtitle is center "right"

Tags: html, css

I need to center a title and in the next line, i have to write a subtitle that ends at the right of the title. Example:

```
                     Here is my title
                             subtitle
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: @Doomenik why you ask a plunkr example ? when there is a StackOverflow snippet available ?

Comment: @Doomenik plunkr  or jsfiddle or other sites, are external sites and links can easily become unusable for future users that come and search/look at this question. All code ( question and answer ) is recommended to be here, on Stack Overflow, not on some external site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using Custom Data Attributes and Pseudo-Elements or using simple css, it totally depends on you. **Below is the solution**:

```css
.page-title {
 text-align: center;
}
h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
h1:after {
 content: attr(data-subtitle);
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0px;
}
.another h1 {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.another span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-title">
 <h1 data-subtitle="subtitle">Here is my title</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-title another">
 <h1>Here is my title <span>subtitle</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want the two in the same div, but then style them separately.

So something like...

```
<div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Here's my title</h1>
    <br>
    <h3 style="text-align: right">My subtitle</h3>
</div>
```

Note that the size of the div is important, because if it is defined to be the whole length of the browser, this will look really weird. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The <br> want be necessary cause hx adds width: 100% and a bigger line-Height. But this would work for sure.

Comment: You're right. I didn't really test it out to see what would happen with the `<br>` tag. I don't usually mess with HTML and CSS that much, but I figured this question was something within my realm of knowledge.

Comment: @Doomenik More like [`width: auto`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/) (nitpickiiiing)